# iPhone - Loading local images from a local xml file

Tags: iphone, resources, local

How come I can load a local xml file from the main bundle, but I can't load images?

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

This gets loaded (i know because I can trace it)
/Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/5B888456-40FF-4C72-A2ED-5D5CFA287777/MyApp.app/test.xml

This image never loads (nor does any image):
/Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/5B888456-40FF-4C72-A2ED-5D5CFA287777/MyApp.app/background.png

Comment: What do you mean when you say the image never loads?  How are you attempting to load it?

Comment: -1. Not enough code, no code showing expected vs actual behaviour (e.g. with asserts?)...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]`.

This will load background.png (which should be located in your Resources folder in Xcode).

Comment: I'm trying to compose a string to send to another method that loads the image. It takes a string, then uses

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgPath];

to compose an NSURLConnection to retrieve the image. I know that sounds convoluted, but the image I'm trying to load may or may not be in the mainBundle. If the image is on a remote server, it loads fine by sending the correct URL, but I can't get it to load from the main bundle. If the image IS in the mainBundle, what string do I pass to the method?

Comment: Why not check imageNamed first and if it fails, construct your URL?

Answer (score 3):

You say in a comment that you're composing a NSURL for the path.  To do this for a local file system path, such as a file in your bundle, you need to use `NSURL fileURLWithPath:`.

Comment: But the question is regarding loading the local images. Thus, it's not necessary to use NSURL & then give it in UIImage method.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities here:

1) Either your image file name doesn't proper. That means, file name is case sensitive. So might be issue of capital-small letters.

2) You might have unchecked the target name from your image property. That means your images are not a member of the target of your project which you are compiling. To verify this, right click on any image name inside your XCode poject --> Select Get Info --> Select Targets tab from the File Info dialog --> Verify the status of the checkbox near the target name/s. In case, it is selected/checked then there is a strange issue. But if it's not selected/unchecked, that means the image is not being added to the bundle file which is created after compilation.

**The third possibility here is you might not have added the image which you're referring. Re-check your project hierarchy & see all the resources are there or not.**

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
UIImage *testimg = [UIImage imageNamed:myfilename];

if (nil==testimg) [testimg initWithContentsOfURL:myurl];
```

I'm away from compiler right now so I can't check whether you might need to download it to an NSData object before making it an image. You should also put the initWithContents... in a try... catch... finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Use the following code

[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background" ofType:@"png"]];

Answer (score 0):

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"bundle://background.png"];